# How to compile TypeScript files to JavaScript using Vue.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, webpack

I'm trying to compile `TypeScript` files into `JavaScript` files using `tsconfig.json` file.
The `tsconfig.json` files is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.test.ts"
  ]
}
```

The above configs work fine and create compiled `JavaScript` files in the build folder. If I use `node run index.js` inside the `build` folder, it also works fine.
But if I import the `index.js` file from the `build` folder into `vue` component, it does not work and throws the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
```

I tried to fix by adding:

```
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```

but no luck.
I also tried the recommended config from official docs:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "strict": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./test-app/src/assets/js"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.test.ts"
  ]
}
```

it throws the following error:

```
TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function
```

I'm already requiring `fs` in `ts` file.

The goal is to use compiled `JavaScript` files into `Vue.js` app.
can anybody help me out what I'm missing in `tsconfig.json` file?
or
is there anyother way to compile `ts` into `js` using `vue.js`?
many thanks.

Comment: It looks like a problem in your index.js, please post that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Change the target and module to "esnext"

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./test-app/src/assets/js"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.test.ts"
  ]
}
```

However, I would not recommend importing built files in your .vue component, as you need to constantly build them for them to be updated. Here is a page from the vue.js doc on how to integrate typescript: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html

Comment: thank you for the answer. I created the app with class style. I'm trying to import `ts` file using `import` statement and trying to call a method from the imported file, but it fails.